# I am trying to use spannable on Marshamallow. Its giving me incorrect output

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

```
        SpannableString text = new SpannableString("RAHUL");
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(white), 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(blue), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        headerHolder.mTextViewLabel.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I am getting only 'HL' as output.

Comment: Expected output is RAHUL in two different colors ie RAH in white and UL in blue.

Comment: this is because both `white` and `blue` are 0 (or at least bits 24-31 are zeros)

Comment: @pskink  
I was using butterknife for injecting colors. @BindColor(R.color.blue) int blue; @BindColor(R.color.white) int white; I guess some problem with that.If i use Color.BLUE instead it is working fine.

Comment: Log.d the values of blue and white,  what are they?

Comment: @pskink yeah, they are 0 only.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check this with output

```
  SpannableString text = new SpannableString("RAHUL");
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 3, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        tv.setText(text);
```

**Output on Marshmallow**

[image]

Hope it will help you

Comment: I am using butterknife for injecting colors.
 @BindColor(R.color.blue)
    int blue;

    @BindColor(R.color.white)
    int white;

I guess some problem with that.If i use Color.BLUE instead it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your start and end arguments are wrong for the second `setSpan`:

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("RAHUL");
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 3, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
headerHolder.mTextViewLabel.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be help to you
change

```
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(white), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(blue), 3, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

instead of this

```
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(white), 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(blue), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```